# Laravel Hash with Slash

Tags: laravel, hash

I'm using hash to send protected email through URL to activate account

```
Hash::make($data["email"]);
```

but the hash result is

```
%242y%2410%24xaiB/eO6knk8sLdIUFrudux8IgwSsNYGnwdaKHi2ZVptWzSuH2Qe6
```

there is a slash in hash code, so my route didn't work well, is there to customize this hash? or is there any other function to make a better hash?

Comment: why you show hash code in url?I think it's not better to show hash code in url

Comment: Data that should be parts of urls should be urlencoded. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: so, how to send a protected url? like product/1 when 1 is a product id. how to convert it hard to read @ImtiazPabel

Comment: @yudijohn you can check this issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5956

Comment: If you are trying to hide 'ids' you can use 'hashids', 1 => jak3ian2izk ... but for what you are doing I am not sure why you are hashing the email address.

Comment: @lagbox i need send invitation email that containt a link that send id and email, is it need be secure?

Comment: @yudijohn use a another filed like "UUID" and store a random string on here.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna get rid of forward slashes, you got to use `str_replace()`

```
str_replace ('/', '', Hash::make($data["email"])));
```